# RabbitMQ slow to publish/consume messages

Tags: c#, .net, redis, rabbitmq

I'm trying to set up my applications in kind of a "pipeline" schema: 
Application 1 publishes a message to queue 1.
Application 2 reads that message and publishes to queue 2.
Application 3 reads that message and publishes to queue 3, and so on.

However, i'm experiencing a varying level of latency between the time one application publishes a message and the next one reads it. Sometimes it is very fast (sub-milissecond) and sometimes it gets really slow (over 1 second).
Communication between applications MUST be very fast, consistently (it is a requirement).

All applications are .NET Framwework 4.7.2, with RabbitMQ.Client 5.1.0. We encapsulated RabbitMQ with our own code for our current needs, so we are not working with any frameworks such as EasyNetQ.

We already tried optimising our own code, so it does not appear to be an Application's problem. (we might be wrong, tho, and might not be analyzing correctly)

Message size is similar between all applications, so that should not be a problem. In fact, we tried with small and large (5MB+) messages and this latency problem kept happening.

We do keep 2 connections per application open with RabbitMQ, as reusing the same connection for publishing and consuming messages is a very broken thing with RabbitMQ. Also we reduced the amount of channels we create by reusing most of them once it is open.

My publisher code is the standard publishing code, the same thing for the consumer.

We do, however:
- Use durable exchanges (not the default one)
- Use non-durable queues (to seek a better performance)

Comment: you haven't asked a question.....

Comment: since you are new, you have to think carefully about creating a self contained question on SO.  SO is not like a forum for random conversations about problems. Its for specific questions

Comment: also unsure why you have tagged redis as well

Comment: As an aside... why are you using a queue rather than a direct socket connection? Or alternatively you could use streaming system like kafka?

Comment: suggest to see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/best-practices.html

Comment: Practically every time someone thinks RabbitMQ is the cause of their issue, it is in fact the application code they have written. The only way you can prove this is a RabbitMQ issue is to provide code to reproduce it, or TCP packet captures showing that RabbitMQ is introducing the latency.